# Python cx_Oracle error "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, python-3.6, cx-oracle

How fix this error, I use python3.6 and I use Oracle database 11g, I want to connect my python to oracle database, but shows error, how can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
#importing module
import cx_Oracle

#create a table in oracle database
try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('db_employees/root@localhost')

    #Now execute the sqlquery
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into employees values(2171114103970002, raden, ceo, 01031997, batam, 001)")

    #commit that insert the provided database
    con.commit()
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)

#by writing finally if any error occurs
#then also we can close the all database operation
finally:
    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if con:
        con.close()
```

This is messages error:

```
C:\Python36>python "D:\testing.py"
There is a problem with Oracle DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\testing.py", line 20, in <module>
    if cursor:
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined
```

Comment: Please review how you format code.  I've edited your post to format it cleanly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the installation instructions: [Installing cx_Oracle on Windows](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows).

The error is saying you need a 32-bit Oracle client library.  You can get one from [32-bit Windows Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html) (The 64-bit libraries are [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) if anyone needs them)  Any version up to 19c will connect to Oracle DB 11.2.  Instructions are at the foot of the page.  Make sure you have the correct VS redistributable installed.

Comment: I have followed the steps that have been shown on github but still have not worked and still have errors

,I use Python 3.6.5 (32 bit)
cx_Oracle 7.2.1
Windows 10(64 bit)

Comment: this is my details error i have installed in 32bit and 64 bit 
https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/340

Comment: thank you Christopher, the second link helped me. But the first one is corrupted.

Comment: I've updated them - thanks.  (Where in doubt, try Google!)

Answer (score 0):

Check your path to see if the client is on it, in some cases the path is not set to point the client or contain invalid characters on it and the python library can't access to it.

You can check here a similar issue https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and here are the steps how I fixed this -

1. Download latest 64-bit version of oracle basic instantClient from:
   https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

In my case I have downloaded - windows.x64-19.10.0.0.0dbru.zip

2. Unzip the Oracle instantClient and copy all .dll files
   [image]
3. Copy these .dll files from Oracle instantclient directory to the python directory

[image]